# What is a correct way to setup protobuf and grpc for cpp project?

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a cpp project, and I want to build everything from source, to get latest things likned in. So under my project root I've created a `3rd_party` folder and assemble following script:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool curl make g++ unzip -y
git clone https://github.com/google/protobuf.git
cd protobuf
git submodule update --init --recursive
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make check
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
cd ..

echo installing grpc
git clone --recurse-submodules -b v1.43.0 https://github.com/grpc/grpc
export MY_INSTALL_DIR=$HOME/.local
be sure that its exists
cd grpc
mkdir -p cmake/build
pushd cmake/build
cmake -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON       -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF       -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$MY_INSTALL_DIR       ../..
make -j
make install
popd
```

i've encountered following flaws:

- grpc v1.43.0 clones 3rd party submodule protoc v3.18, which after build has problems - protoc binary says "cpp plugin not found", when trying to generate

To overcome that I've copied sources obtained in the first part of script, to 3rd party subfolder of second part, to gurantee it to be 3.19 - then after compilation protoc working great, plugins are in place, and grpc is linked against latest version.

Very weird issue, needs understanding why it clones outdated version, and why 3.18 has no plugins under same build parameters as 3.19

- in cmakelists `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)` fails at all
- find_package( gRPC REQUIRED ) is not operating properly:

```
Found package configuration file:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     /home/a/.local/lib/cmake/grpc/gRPCConfig.cmake
[cmake] 
[cmake]   but it set gRPC_FOUND to FALSE so package "gRPC" is considered to be NOT
[cmake]   FOUND.  Reason given by package:
[cmake] 
[cmake]   The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing:
[cmake]   protobuf::libprotobuf protobuf::libprotoc
```

---

Question

How can I write script, that in an empty folder will get me everything, related to grpc 3rd party libs and tools, that I need for project?

Comment: why not using CMake FetchContent() to grab all your third parties instead ?

Comment: @Mizux - FetchContent has a lot of drawbacks... requiring an internet connection for your build is an absolute non-starter in many corporate environments for one, but even worse is that FetchContent means importing someone else's CMake code into your build, which can literally do whatever... you'll have to carefully read it to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps I took:

```shell
$ mkdir .local
$ export INSTALL_PREFIX="$PWD/.local"
$ export CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja  # optional, but recommended

$ git clone --recurse-submodules -b v3.19.3 --depth 1 https://github.com/google/protobuf.git
$ pushd protobuf
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PREFIX
$ make -j$(nproc)
$ make install
$ popd

$ git clone --recurse-submodules -b v1.43.0 --depth 1 https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git
$ cmake -S grpc -B .build/grpc \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$INSTALL_PREFIX \
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$INSTALL_PREFIX \
    -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON \
    -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER=package \
    -DABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD=ON
$ cmake --build .build/grpc --target install
...

$ mkdir example
$ echo "int main () { return 0; }" > example/main.cpp
$ vim example/CMakeLists.txt
$ cat example/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(example)

find_package(gRPC REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE gRPC::grpc++)

$ cmake -S example -B .build/example \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$INSTALL_PREFIX
$ cmake --build .build/example
...
```

I build protobuf separately because gRPC doesn't set up its dependencies in CMake correctly when using its internal protobuf build (I tried both ways). This involves passing `--prefix` to protobuf's `./configure` script and passing `-DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER=package` to gRPC's CMake build. The latter is a gRPC-specific variable that tells it not to build protobuf, but to search for it instead. I tell gRPC where to find protobuf by setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, which is a standard variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very useful, this should be posted at grpc quickstart page, so beginners may actually quick start!